# Microsoft Access Export to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

Is it possible to export from microsoft access into microsoft excel, but have the columns on the ledt and the rows going down? I know the default export has it the other way arround.

Data is being being provided to a 3-rd party but they want in in the above format

So like:

Column1 | Row1 | Row2

Column2 | Row1 | Row2

Column3 | Row1 | Row2

Comment: Export then transpose?

Answer (score 0):

Either open the table as a recordset and loop this multiple time filling a temporary table; then export this.

Or export the table *as is* to Excel, then call Transpose to "rotate" the filled range:

[TRANSPOSE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

Comment: Using a temp table wouldn't work, as you would hit the limit of 255 columns in a table.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to do this in Access rather than looking at using `TRANSPOSE` in Excel, you will probably want to use some VBA to loop the fields in a recordset. Something like this should give you an idea (you will need to set a reference to the Excel object library in order to use early binding):

```
Sub sExportExcelTransposed()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim objXL As New Excel.Application
    Dim objXLBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objXLSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strXLFile As String
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM dbo_svr_Country ORDER BY CountryName ASC;", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    If Not (rsData.BOF And rsData.EOF) Then
        strXLFile = "J:\downloads\transpose.xlsx"
        If Len(Dir(strXLFile)) > 0 Then Kill strXLFile
        Set objXLBook = objXL.Workbooks.Add
        Set objXLSheet = objXLBook.Worksheets(1)
        lngCol = 1
        For lngRow = 1 To rsData.Fields.Count
            objXLSheet.Cells(lngRow, lngCol) = rsData.Fields(lngRow - 1).name
        Next lngRow
        lngCol = 2
        Do
            For lngRow = 1 To rsData.Fields.Count
                objXLSheet.Cells(lngRow, lngCol) = rsData.Fields(lngRow - 1).Value
            Next lngRow
            lngCol = lngCol + 1
            rsData.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsData.EOF
        objXLBook.SaveAs strXLFile
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set objXLSheet = Nothing
    objXLBook.Close
    Set objXLBook = Nothing
    objXL.Quit
    Set objXL = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sExportExcelTransposed", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,